# Android notification never shows up

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-notifications

I'm and making a simple reminder app with notification and as the title says my android notification never shows up.

I've made a broadcast class like so:

```
class ReminderBroadcast : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            var builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "notifyUser")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                    .setContentTitle("Memo reminder")
                    .setContentText("You have a memo set to the current time!")
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)

            var notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)

            notificationManager.notify( 200, builder.build())

    }
}
```

In my MainActivity I am creating a channel using the following method:

```
private fun createNotificationChannel(){

            val name: CharSequence = "UserNotificationChannel"

            val description: String = "Channel for notifying users"

            val importance: Int = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT

            val channel: NotificationChannel = NotificationChannel("notifyUser", name, importance)
            channel.description = description

            val notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java)

            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)

       // }

    }
```

and finally I create the notification in a fragment which holds the new reminder form. Upon creating the form (onClickListener for submit button), I create the notification like so:

```
val intent = Intent(context, ReminderBroadcast::class.java)
val pendingIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0)

val alarmManager: AlarmManager = requireContext().getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager

//set notification to trigger 5 seconds from now
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+5000, pendingIntent)

//set direction
findNavController().popBackStack()
```

The notification never shows and I've been clueless for days as to what I'm missing. Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: only add your notification chanel and it works, remember create before you start your application

Answer (score 2):

The reason that you are not getting a notification is the notification channel:-

*Starting in Android 8.0 (API level 26), all notifications must be assigned to a channel. For each channel, you can set the visual and auditory behaviour that is applied to all notifications in that channel. Then, users can change these settings and decide which notification channels from your app should be intrusive or visible at all.*

Solution

Step 1. Create a notification channel-

```
     object NotificationHelper {
    
      fun createNotificationChannel(context: Context, importance: Int, showBadge: Boolean, name: String, description: String) {
    
    
        // 1
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
          // 2
          val channelId = "${context.packageName}-$name"
          val channel = NotificationChannel(channelId, name, importance)
          channel.description = description
          channel.setShowBadge(showBadge)
    
          // 3
          val notificationManager = context.getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java)
          notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }
      }
    }
```

Step 2. Register the channel in your application class

```
class AppClass : Application() {

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()

NotificationHelper.createNotificationChannel(this,
  NotificationManagerCompat.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT, false,
  getString(R.string.app_name), "App notification channel.")

  }
}
```

Step 3. Register this app class in Manifest

```
 <application
    android:name=".AppClass"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Note: Learn more about the notification channel through this link: https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels

Answer (score 0):

Only add you notification channel, remember create when you start your application

Answer (score 0):

The level of notification is set when the app is first installed, if the level has changed you'll need to uninstall the app and re-install it again. I've been caught by this a few times.